# Query para coletar dados de várias colunas da mesma linha, por Primary Key do registro

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tudo tranquilo?!

Vejam se conseguem me ajudar!

Da query abaixo (uso phpMyAdmin), estou precisando apenas trazer os resultados de "LETRAA", "LETRAT", "LETRAG" e "LETRAF" para a tela do browser (via PHP), porém não sei qual parte do código da query deve ser alterada para chegar ao resultado que preciso.

```
SELECT
    tr_id,
    LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'A','')) LETRAA,
    LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'T','')) LETRAT,
    LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'G','')) LETRAG,
    LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'F','')) LETRAF
FROM (
    SELECT
        tr_id,
        concat(
        tr_1 ,tr_2 ,tr_3 ,tr_4 ,tr_5 ,tr_6 ,tr_7 ,tr_8 ,tr_9 ,tr_10,
        tr_11,tr_12,tr_13,tr_14,tr_15,tr_16,tr_17,tr_18,tr_19,tr_20,
        tr_21,tr_22,tr_23,tr_24,tr_25,tr_26,tr_27,tr_28,tr_29,tr_30,
        tr_31,tr_32,tr_33,tr_34,tr_35,tr_36,tr_37,tr_38,tr_39,tr_40,
        tr_41,tr_42,tr_43,tr_44,tr_45,tr_46,tr_47,tr_48,tr_49,tr_50,
        tr_51,tr_52,tr_53,tr_54,tr_55,tr_56,tr_57,tr_58,tr_59,tr_60,
        tr_61,tr_52,tr_63,tr_64,tr_65,tr_66,tr_67,tr_68,tr_69,tr_70,
        tr_71,tr_52,tr_73,tr_74,tr_75,tr_76,tr_77,tr_78,tr_79,tr_80,
        tr_81
        ) RESPOSTAS
    FROM
        tetra_respostas
    WHERE
        tr_id = 11
) TAB
```

Para melhor entender, segue abaixo uma imagem do resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo, o código da página a ser exibida, mas mesmo assim os dados não estão vindo da consulta. Por isso acho que é alguma coisa no código da query.

```
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['tr_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['RESPOSTAS']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['LETRAA']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['LETRAT']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['LETRAG']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Tetragrama['LETRAF']; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Como você diz que o resultado no phpMyAdmin está correto então tudo leva a crer que o problema não está com a expressão SQL, mas talvez eu não tenha entendido sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente achei o erro!!!

Eles estão nas linhas 17 e 18 da query, em: "tr_52" e "tr_52", onde o correto é: "tr_62" e "tr_72", respectivamente... por isso os resultados não estavam sendo exibidos como esperado.

```
SELECT
tr_id,
LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'A','')) LETRAA,
LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'T','')) LETRAT,
LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'G','')) LETRAG,
LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'F','')) LETRAF
  FROM (
   SELECT
    tr_id,
    concat(
    tr_1, tr_2 ,tr_3 ,tr_4 ,tr_5 ,tr_6 ,tr_7 ,tr_8 ,tr_9 ,tr_10,
    tr_11,tr_12,tr_13,tr_14,tr_15,tr_16,tr_17,tr_18,tr_19,tr_20,
    tr_21,tr_22,tr_23,tr_24,tr_25,tr_26,tr_27,tr_28,tr_29,tr_30,
    tr_31,tr_32,tr_33,tr_34,tr_35,tr_36,tr_37,tr_38,tr_39,tr_40,
    tr_41,tr_42,tr_43,tr_44,tr_45,tr_46,tr_47,tr_48,tr_49,tr_50,
    tr_51,tr_52,tr_53,tr_54,tr_55,tr_56,tr_57,tr_58,tr_59,tr_60,
    tr_61,tr_62,tr_63,tr_64,tr_65,tr_66,tr_67,tr_68,tr_69,tr_70,
    tr_71,tr_72,tr_73,tr_74,tr_75,tr_76,tr_77,tr_78,tr_79,tr_80,
    tr_81
    ) RESPOSTAS
   FROM
    tetra_respostas
   WHERE
    tr_id = idResp
) TAB
```

Sempre suspeitei de algum erro no SQL... ufa!!! Segue o jogo...

Answer (score 0):

Se a consulta no MyPhpAdmin está trazendo o resultado desejado, só está faltando imprimir o valor das variáveis em cada  da sua tabela.

Dá pra ver que você conseguiu imprimir o código 11 na coluna tr_id;
vc só precisa imprimir as demais em cada

vc deve ter feito algo assim:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php print $resultado['tr_id'];?></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

É só completar:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php print $resultado['tr_id'];?></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><?php print $resultado['LETRAA'];?></td>
  <td><?php print $resultado['LETRAT'];?></td>
  <td><?php print $resultado['LETRAG'];?></td>
  <td><?php print $resultado['LETRAF'];?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Se você usar aliases no nome da coluna o erro persiste? Exemplo.: SELECT
    tr_id,
    LENGTH(TAB.RESPOSTAS)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TAB.RESPOSTAS,'A','')) as LETRAA,